# RazorPages Partial handler not found? 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to use a `Partial` to dynamically fill a part of my page.

my `Import.cshtml`

```cs
@page
@model ImportViewModel

<h2>Data import</h2>
<div>
    <p id="IsImportRunningPartial"></p>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function LoadIsImportRunningPartial() {
            $('#IsImportRunningPartial').load('Import&handler=IsImportRunningPartial');
        }
        $(document).ready(LoadIsImportRunningPartial);
        setInterval(LoadIsImportRunningPartial, 1000);
    </script>
}
```

My `Import.cshtml.cs`

```cs
    public sealed class ImportViewModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet() { }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetIsImportRunningPartial()
        {
            var dummy = 1;
            return Partial("_IsImportRunningPartial", false);
        }
    }
```

And my `_IsImportRunningPartial.cshtml`

```cs
@model bool

Data import is @(Model?"":"not") running.
```

The main page is loaded. However, I keep getting 404s on the Get to `Import&handler=IsImportRunningPartial`. I set a breakpoint at the `dummy` line, but it seems the handler method is never called?!

I think I'm following the book. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page model is `ImportView` not `Import`. And should use `?` to append the querystring:

```
ImportView?handler=IsImportRunningPartial
```

Comment: Hi and Thanks. However, this first part of your answer is incorrect. You should reference the cshtml file name in the URL. My mistake was using the incorrect separator in the query string. (I found a second error in loading the partial, I editted that). In the end it was just a dumb typo.